# Handler (android.os.Handler) sending message to a Handler on a dead thread - Android background thread AlarmManager with Upload Service

Tags: multithreading, alarmmanager, intentservice

I am currently using the AlarmManager, Broadcast receiver and Intent Service to implement upload service to server rub by background instead  of Ui Main Thread but the problem is when it comes to the execution , there is no response for the upload message . At least,  in the logcat, I can see any message reporting the progress for the upload weven I have typed and tested correctly.

But afer the upload service is finished , it shows 
java.lang.RuntimeException: Handler (android.os.Handler) sending message to a Handler on a dead thread

Would you please tell me what else is missing ?

The below is my code

Intnt Service

```
public class TaskService extends IntentService {

    public TaskService() {
        super("TaskService");
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent arg0) {

        // Do some task
        Log.i("TaskService","Service running");
        boolean ss = uploadRecording("TEST_RECORD" , "test.mp4" , "http://210.177.246.83/uploadFile");
        Log.d("Is file uploaded" , String.valueOf(ss));
    }

    public boolean uploadRecording(String directoryname , String filename , String destination) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        boolean result = false;

        String destinationPath = destination;       

        File tes = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + File.separator + directoryname);
        File frecord = new File(tes.getAbsolutePath() + File.separator + filename);
        if(tes.exists()){
            if(frecord.exists()){

                List< NameValuePair> httpContents = new ArrayList< NameValuePair>();
                httpContents.add(new BasicNameValuePair("file",frecord.getAbsolutePath())); 

                HttpClient client=new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost post=new HttpPost(destinationPath);
                try{
                    //setup multipart entity
                    MultipartEntity entity=new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);

                    for(int i=0;i< httpContents.size();i++){
                        //identify param type by Key
                        if(httpContents.get(i).getName().equals("file")){
                            File f=new File(httpContents.get(i).getValue());
                            FileBody fileBody=new FileBody(f);
                            entity.addPart("file"+i,fileBody);
                        }
                    }
                    post.setEntity(entity);
                    //create response handler
                    //execute and get response
                    HttpResponse uploadReponse = client.execute(post);
                    Log.d("debug" , "Response : " + uploadReponse);
                    if(uploadReponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200){
                        result = true;
                        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }     
            }
        }

        return result;       
    }   
}
```

BroadCast Receiver

```
public static String ACTION_ALARM = "com.alarammanager.alaram";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        Log.i("Alarm Receiver", "Entered");
        Toast.makeText(context, "Entered", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        String action = bundle.getString(ACTION_ALARM);
        if (action.equals(ACTION_ALARM)) {
            Log.i("Alarm Receiver", "If loop");
            Toast.makeText(context, "If loop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent inService = new Intent(context, TaskService.class);
            inService.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startService(inService);
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("Alarm Receiver", "Else loop");
            Toast.makeText(context, "Else loop", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Main Acitvity

```
public class AlaramScheduleActivity extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

    }

    public void btnStartSchedule(View v) {

        try {
            AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this
                    .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                    AlaramReceiver.class);
            intent.putExtra(AlaramReceiver.ACTION_ALARM,
                    AlaramReceiver.ACTION_ALARM);

            final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this,
                    1234567, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,
                    System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 10, pIntent);

            toast("Started...");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    public void btnCancelSchedules(View v) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                AlaramReceiver.class);
        intent.putExtra(AlaramReceiver.ACTION_ALARM,
                AlaramReceiver.ACTION_ALARM);

        final PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 1234567,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) this
                .getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        alarms.cancel(pIntent);
        toast("Canceled...");
    }

    public void toast(String message) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
```

Android Manifest

INTERNET Permisson  is acquired

```
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>

   <service android:name=".TaskService" >
</service>

<receiver
    android:name="AlaramReceiver"
    android:process=":remote" >
</receiver>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in Toast message shown from IntentService. 
Fix is simple: create Handler in onCreate of your service and post Runnable to show toast from it.

```
public class TaskService extends IntentService {
...
    private Handler mHandler;

    protected void onCreate() {
        mHandler = new Handler();
    }

    ...

    public boolean uploadRecording(... {
    ...
        mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Upload Success", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    ...
    }

}
```

Internally toast uses Handler to communicate with INotificationManager. Once toast created it create instance of Handler, which uses looper from the thread it is created. In your case it is HandlerThread of IntentService. It is interrupted once service finished all work. That is why it is dead.